# Error: No suitable driver found for jdbc, al ejecutar .jar

Tags: java, mysql, jar

Cuando quiero ejecutar el .jar de mi proyecto genera el error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://containers-us-west-118.railway.app:6869/railway, sin embargo cuando ejecuto el proyecto en netbeans 18 no da ningun error y conecta perfectamente con la base de datos, ejecute el proyecto tanto con una base de datos local asi como una en la nube y solo hay error con el ejecutable ¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?